# The idea that ... seems absurd OR the idea seems absurd that

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, phrase-usage, determiners

The following sentence:

> 1. The idea that we are all created equal seems absurd to me.

Seems better to me than:

> 2. The idea seems absurd that we are all created equal.

Is it correct to use seems/that in the way the **second sentence** does?

Note: these sentences are for example only and do not necessarily reflect my own views.

Comment: Both are valid; the first is more usual, because the second may be more difficult to interpret.

Answer (score -1):

The second one is 100% incorrect. It is common, which is a shame, but **that** is a determiner that should come after the noun it is about to describe--in this case **idea**. **Seems absurd** should follow the entirety of the idea. Thus, the first one is correct.